# How to add vf="hflip" flag on videos in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, metadata

I just want to add vf="hflip" flag in video file. I have used the ffmpeg to update the video but it will take much time to flip the video.
Is there any way to add hflip tag in metadata of video?

Comment: You can rotate with metadata, but I am unaware of any method involving metadata to horizontally flip.